# In React.js, how can I change header of the page according to url in app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change header of the page accodring to the url in React.js.

If url is 'localhost:3000/recommendation/loading', I want to show the component 'LoadingMainHeader' at header.

Else if url is not same as above, I want to show the component 'MainHeader' at header.

My code is as below, but it doesn't works. (only MainHeader is shown)
Please let me know how to fix the code. Thanks.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, location } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './pages/Main';
import Recommendation from './pages/Recommendation';
import Loading from './pages/Loading';
import RandomRecResult from './pages/RandomRecResult';
import SelectedRecResult from './pages/SelectedRecResult';
import MainHeader from './components/common/MainHeader';
import LoadingMainHeader from './components/common/LoadingMainHeader';

function App(location) {
  if (location.pathname !== '/recommendation/loading')
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MainHeader></MainHeader>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route exact path="/recommendation" component={Recommendation}/>
        <Route exact path="/recommendation/result_random" component={RandomRecResult}/>
        <Route exact path="/recommendation/result_selected" component={SelectedRecResult}/>
      </BrowserRouter>  
    );
  else
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LoadingMainHeader></LoadingMainHeader>
        <Route exact path="/recommendation/loading" component={Loading}/>
      </BrowserRouter>  
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: better approach is to make new header file then in that header file add condition there

Comment: Remove the `location` parameter from your `function App(location)` line, it is shadowing the actual `location` you want to use. Or use `window.location.pathname` instead (best do both).

Comment: Here's the better way, using Switch: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-meadow-ebgov?file=/src/App.js (your mechanism of comparing location to a string and using an if else block is essentially exactly what `Switch` does)

Comment: @ChrisG Wow!! I solved this problem by using Switch. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @hu7sy Thank you for your opinion!

Answer (score 0):

check what is getting in location.pathname using the console.

or
try to implement with useLocation hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './pages/Main';
import Recommendation from './pages/Recommendation';
import Loading from './pages/Loading';
import RandomRecResult from './pages/RandomRecResult';
import SelectedRecResult from './pages/SelectedRecResult';
import MainHeader from './components/common/MainHeader';
import LoadingMainHeader from './components/common/LoadingMainHeader';

function App() {
let location = useLocation()
  if (location.pathname !== '/recommendation/loading')
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MainHeader></MainHeader>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route exact path="/recommendation" component={Recommendation}/>
        <Route exact path="/recommendation/result_random" component={RandomRecResult}/>
        <Route exact path="/recommendation/result_selected" component={SelectedRecResult}/>
      </BrowserRouter>  
    );
  else
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LoadingMainHeader></LoadingMainHeader>
        <Route exact path="/recommendation/loading" component={Loading}/>
      </BrowserRouter>  
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But by using { useLocation }, my problem didn't solve.  I solved the problem by using window.location.pathname. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

***You are doing in a wrong way.***

Here is the solution: [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-6sl8g?file=/index.js)

**Note**: This is a blueprint how to achieve you goal.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Hope you have a nice day!